# how to set the content size of a scrollView Dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView and on that scrollView, i have many labels and textView along with one tableView. scrollView is working perfectly fine when the no. of rows are less in tablView but if tableView have more number of rows then i am not able to full content and even i am loosing lots of information in tableView because the tableView isn't scrollable. i have added all the lables, textView and tableView as a subview of scrollview. Can anyone help me in that so i can get full tableView and make it proper scrollable.

Here is my code to set the content size of scrollView.

```
float maxHeight = 0;

    for(UIView *v in [self.scrollView subviews]){
        if(v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height > maxHeight)
            maxHeight = v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height;
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, maxHeight+100);
```

Comment: why are you adding 1000 to max height?

Comment: code seems to be OK, but this is not working, then problem must by lying with when you are calling this code

Comment: can you post screenshot my friend??

Comment: u want a screenshot of what. an incomplete tableView or something else??

Comment: note that instead of `v.frame.origin.x` you should have `v.frame.origin.y`.

Comment: okay. i'll try putting that, looks like i made some mistake. lemme check and come back.

Comment: nothing happened. still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to resize your table, so that it fits all the rows (since as you said, it's not scrollable). I believe that doing so will make all your rows to not be reusable, so if it's a big table you may get performance issues. Also be aware of @David H's answer, so if you really want to do this, you might be better of using another `UIScrollView` instead of the `UITableView` (it won't bring much benefit either way).

Second, you'll need to move all the views beneath the tableview, so that they won't overlap. An easy way to do this is to have those views put together in a different view, so that you only need to move one view instead (in this case however, you'll also need to resize that view accordingly).

Finally, instead of looping through all the `scrollview`'s subviews, it should be easy enough to keep track of the view that is closest to the bottom (this depends on how you generate and add the views to the scroll view).

Comment: for first suggestion, i dont understand how do i use scrollView instead of tableView. isn't it possible to put non scrollable tableview on the top of scrollView. 

and for the 2nd suggestion, it was overlapping earlier but i enabled the paging so now it's nt overlapping..

Comment: It is possible, it just doesn't have some of the benefits of a `UITableView` any longer, and it may also cause some issues.

Answer (score 2):

A tableview is a scroll view subclass, and generally Apple says adding it to another scroll view will cause problems. That said there are ways to make it work. Search here or on google for terms like "how to put a uitableview in a uiscrollview".

EDIT: to make it not scrollable you could put a transparent view over the table view that stops or eats touch events.

Comment: is there ways to put tablview on scrollView without making tableView scrollable.?

Comment: As I suggested above, do the research yourself. With the right code and technique you can do most anything.

Comment: for making it non scrollable, i just disable scrolling from IBoutlet of tableView.

Answer (score 0):

self.scrollingView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,372);

Try this.